# How to change the color of the navigation bar (navBar) in iOS 15

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, swiftui, toolbar

How do I change the navBar color to red in SwiftUI using an extension I want to apply to my view?

My extensions

```swift
func createToolbarSettings(dismissAction: (() -> Void)?, title: LocalizedStringKey, tag: String) -> some View {
    self.toolbar(content: {
        ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarLeading) {
            Button(action: {
                dismissAction?()
            }, label: {
                Image.arrowBack
                    .resizable()
                    .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                    .frame(width: .genericFrame, height: .genericFrame)
            })
            .tag(tag)
        }
        ToolbarItem(placement: .principal) {
            Text(title)
                .font(.montserratFontMapping(ofSize: .genericFrame, weight: .medium))
                .foregroundColor(.white)
        }
    })
}
```

Answer (score -1):

For this you can create a custom modifier that applies the desired appearance to the navigation bar.You can do this by

```
    extension View {
func redNavigationBar() -> some View {
    self.modifier(RedNavigationBarModifier())
}}


    struct RedNavigationBarModifier: ViewModifier {
func body(content: Content) -> some View {
    content
        .navigationBarColor(.red)
}}
```

You can then use the redNavigationBar() modifier on any view to apply the red navigation bar color.I have updated your code

```
    func createToolbarSettings(dismissAction: (() -> Void)?, title: LocalizedStringKey, tag: String) -> some View {
self.toolbar(content: {
    ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarLeading) {
        Button(action: {
            dismissAction?()
        }, label: {
            Image.arrowBack
                .resizable()
                .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                .frame(width: .genericFrame, height: .genericFrame)
        })
        .tag(tag)
    }
    ToolbarItem(placement: .principal) {
        Text(title)
            .font(.montserratFontMapping(ofSize: .genericFrame, weight: .medium))
            .foregroundColor(.white)
    }
})
.redNavigationBar() } // Apply the red navigation bar color
```

Comment: if I'm not mistaken, it is not possible to use navigationBarColor 
navigationBarColor  = "Value of type 'RedNavigationBarModifier.Content' (aka '_ViewModifier_Content<RedNavigationBarModifier>') has no member 'navigationBarColor'"

Answer (score -1):

```
struct NavigationBarModifier: ViewModifier {
    
    var backgroundColor: UIColor?
    var titleColor: UIColor?
    
    init(backgroundColor: UIColor?, titleColor: UIColor?) {
        self.backgroundColor = backgroundColor
        let coloredAppearance = UINavigationBarAppearance()
        coloredAppearance.configureWithTransparentBackground()
        coloredAppearance.backgroundColor = backgroundColor
        coloredAppearance.titleTextAttributes = [.foregroundColor: titleColor ?? .white]
        coloredAppearance.largeTitleTextAttributes = [.foregroundColor: titleColor ?? .white]
        
        UINavigationBar.appearance().standardAppearance = coloredAppearance
        UINavigationBar.appearance().compactAppearance = coloredAppearance
        UINavigationBar.appearance().scrollEdgeAppearance = coloredAppearance
    }
    
    func body(content: Content) -> some View {
        ZStack{
            content
            VStack {
                GeometryReader { geometry in
                    Color(self.backgroundColor ?? .clear)
                        .frame(height: geometry.safeAreaInsets.top)
                        .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.top)
                    Spacer()
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

extension View {
    
    func navigationBarColor(backgroundColor: UIColor?, titleColor: UIColor?) -> some View {
        self.modifier(NavigationBarModifier(backgroundColor: backgroundColor, titleColor: titleColor))
    }
    
}
```

this work

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).